# Compare 2 column A's in 2 different sheets and if they match, check Column B in the second sheet and return "FALSE" in the first sheet if it's blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

I'm trying to have my 'Checkbox' column (Column B in Sheet1) to get filled in with either a TRUE or FALSE value based on two conditions

1. A match between column A's of both sheets
2. If the 'By' column (Column B in Sheet2) is blank -> to return False

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CwS87yOdhZ7LaSUcGEb2vYSdQoSLxDey7PwLBq3qgW8/edit#gid=1855694027

I've been trying to use vlookup but don't know how to introduce the second part of my condition to the formula :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` function and check whether the returned value is blank or not.

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(""<>VLOOKUP(A2:A6,Sheet2!A:B,2,0))
```

This formula is entered in the first row containing the checkbox; you have to remove the checkboxes below to give room to the formula to expand then you can reinsert them.